# What does radio mean when said by sport coaches?

Tags: meaning

I have heard this word commonly used when sports coaches are calling a group to come in. An example of *radio* by a sports coach is:

> Radio, come in guys.

So what does it really mean? I live in Australia, so wondering as well if there are any other people around the world uses this term?

I have not heard any other people other than sports coaches say this.

Comment: Can you share an example of any coach saying this? It typically just means a radio check, to see if communication is good. It's not an official voice procedure or anything.

Comment: In the block quote is an example of what a sports coach might say. Maybe I didn't make it clear enough.

Comment: @CipherBot Michael meant a real-life example. Like a video clip or an article from the sports section of a newspaper. Basically the phrase is unfamiliar and we're looking for more context to work it out.

Comment: Sports teams at a collegiate and professional level are increasingly using some sort of radio to communicate between the coach and players on the field.  The above *could* be referring to that somehow, or it *could* simply be a bit of odd jargon for this particular sport and country.

Comment: I don't *know*, but it seems quite possible there are already (or soon will be) wireless headsets activated by the wearer saying the word ***radio***. At which point they would broadcast any immediately-following words to all other headsets monitoring the shared channel frequency (so the coach can easily address all members of his team even if they're widely spread out on a playing field, for example).

Answer (score 1):

I've never it used, but my guess would be that it is a metaphor implying that the team is not paying attention, that they don't have 'their heads in the game'.

"Come in" is a phrase used in telephonic communication (over the airwaves, walkie-talkie), so its use here suggests that the audience is distracted, far away.

It sounds like a variation of a vernacular usage in US among friends "Earth to [Name], come in [Name]... "